# How IUrlHelper is implemented in CreatedAtActionResult class of ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

`CreatedAtAction` method of `ControllerBase` class returns an instance of the class `CreatedAtActionResult` which creates an instance of `IUrlHelper` interface which is responsible for generating urls.

Inside the method `OnFormatting` of `CreatedAtActionResult` class, the method `Action` of `IUrlHelper` interface is called. But I cannot find anywhere in the open source ASP.NET Core, the implementation of the `Action` method.

Comment: You didn't looked hard enough. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/UrlHelper.cs Just use the GitHub search function and look for `: IUrlHelper` to find the class implementing it

Comment: yes, you are right. thanks. i downloaded the open source and open it from visual studio. it has much better search options.